# How to add non-telephony tablet support for Expo managed workflow react native app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am developing an `React Native` app using `Expo managed workflow`. The app works like a charm on `Android devices`, but when I tried to download it on an tablet that doesn't have `SIM` tray, thus it's not a telephone-like device, it doesn't appear in store. Accesing the link directly, it shows that the device is not supported. Tried to get it on a tablet that does have `SIM` tray, in other words, a bigger telephone, and it works. I have found some info that the `manifest` should use something like `android.hardware.telephony` to be set to `false` in order to work on on tablets with no `SIM` tray. The problem it's that I am using `Expo managed workflow` and I cannot change the `manifest`, so I do not know how to solve this. Ejecting `ExpoKit` it's also not a solution right now. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Also, I am having trouble adding a transparent background icon. Every time I use a .png with transparent background, the expo build user the standard `android.adaptiveIcon.backgroundColor` from `app.json` that's white. So no transparent background. Any help about this would also be appreciated.

Comment: What is the content of the `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` file ?

Comment: @justcodin as stated above, I am using `Expo managed workflow`, so I am not able to access the `Manifest`. I do not want to eject, as my app uses many `expo libraries`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can add that block in the `app.json` file :

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My App",
    "android" : {
       "supportsTablet" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's only for `iOS`.